# Polymorphism in c++ idea of vtable (dynamic binding)

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I was thinking about mechanism of polymorphism in C++ and I can't understand one thing. Here I have very simple piece of code with one class:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int x;
    void fun1();
    double fun2(int, char*);
    void fun3(double, float[]);
};

int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(A) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

On the console there will be printed size of int object (x) - it's obvious. If I modife my class by added keyword virtual the size will change because compiler are adding pointer to array (vtable) of virtual functions. But how it is possible that size of my class doesn't change while writing declarations of new virtual methods of completely different signatures? I mean that:

```
void (*(tab[100]) )(int, double, char*);
```

It's a definition of array which is obliged to has adresses of functions with signature:

```
void fun(int, double, char*);
```

And only this type of functions may be added to this array so why no matter of type of virtual method class contains only one pointer to one virtual array? Where have I made a mistake in my logic?

Comment: To clarify: The vtable is not part of each class instance; it's like a static member and exists only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing first - the standard doesn't say *nothing* about virtual tables. it only talks about virtual functions and polymorphism. every compiler is allowed to implement this feature in any way it likes.

virtual tables are only common implementation of virtual function, it is not mendatory, and the implementation is different in every compiler.

lastly, on my Visual studio 2015, this :

```
class A1 {
    int x;
    void doIT(){}
};

class A2 {
    int x;
    virtual void doIT(){}
};

constexpr int size = sizeof(A1);
constexpr int size2 = sizeof(A2);
```

makes `size` 4 bytes, but `size2` 12 bytes, which breaks your assumptions. 
again, GCC, Clang and even C++/CLI may have different behaviour, and yield different size.

Answer (score 2):

It could be [useful](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/):

> The virtual table is actually quite simple, though it’s a little complex to describe in words. First, every class that uses virtual functions (or is derived from a class that uses virtual functions) is given it’s own virtual table. This table is simply a static array that the compiler sets up at compile time. A virtual table contains one entry for each virtual function that can be called by objects of the class. Each entry in this table is simply a function pointer that points to the most-derived function accessible by that class